# C# WinForms, Adding a usercontrol Dynamically during runtime and controls are invisible?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, visible, dynamically-generated

I'm working on a contact manager, and I want to add controls for contact details such as Phone Number, Email to a usercontrol.  i created a user control called TextPrompt that includes a label and textbox. the code should sort through the contacts Info and add a control for each entree, the program produces no errors(logical, and syntax as far as i can tell). I ran checks to make sure the controls were being added to the panel after the loop ran and it shows the controls are there, but they arent visible during runtime.

```
        List<ContactType> details = contact.ReturnAllContactDetails();
        int y = 0;

        if (contact != null)
        {
            lbl_Name.Text = "";
            if (contact.GetContactValueByType("FirstName") != null) { lbl_Name.Text = contact.GetContactValueByType("FirstName") + " "; }
            if (contact.GetContactValueByType("LastName") != null) { lbl_Name.Text = lbl_Name.Text + contact.GetContactValueByType("LastName"); }
            if (contact.GetContactValueByType("Company") != null) { lbl_Name.Text = lbl_Name.Text + "\n" + contact.GetContactValueByType("Company"); }

            pnl_ContactDetails.BringToFront();
            pnl_ContactDetails.Controls.Clear();
            pnl_ContactDetails.SuspendLayout();
            for(int i = 3; i < details.Count; i++) {
                TextPrompt txtbox = new TextPrompt(details[i]);                 //Textbox to be added
                MessageBox.Show(details[i].value);
                this.pnl_ContactDetails.Controls.Add(txtbox);

                txtbox.Name = details[i].name;                                  //Sets properties
                txtbox.Location = new Point(25, y);
                txtbox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(345, 45);
                txtbox.TextValueChanged += new EventHandler(txtbox_TextChanged);
                txtbox.Show();

                txtbox = (TextPrompt)this.pnl_ContactDetails.Controls[i - 3];   //Checks to make sure controls are on form.
                MessageBox.Show(txtbox.ContactDetails.name);

                y = y + 45;
            }
        }
```

Comment: looks like your list `details` even doesn't have any element? you initialize it and let it there? Hence the `for` loop would never run.

Comment: As mentioned in my post, I have already made sure the data is there along with the controls. The contact.ReturnAllContactDetails() function returns a already initialized List.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you have called `SuspendLayout()` without telling the panel to `ResumeLayout()`

---

```
pnl_ContactDetails.SuspendLayout();
for(int i = 3; i < details.Count; i++)
{
    TextPrompt txtbox = new TextPrompt(details[i]); //Textbox to be added
    MessageBox.Show(details[i].value);

    txtbox.Name = details[i].name; //Sets properties
    txtbox.Location = new Point(25, y);
    txtbox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(345, 45);
    txtbox.TextValueChanged += new EventHandler(txtbox_TextChanged);
    /* txtbox.Show(); */ // Leave this call out in favor of:
    txtbox.Visible = true;
    this.pnl_ContactDetails.Controls.Add(txtbox);

    txtbox = (TextPrompt)this.pnl_ContactDetails.Controls[i - 3]; //Checks to make sure controls are on form.
    MessageBox.Show(txtbox.ContactDetails.name);

    y = y + 45;
}
pnl_ContactDetails.ResumeLayout();
```

---

I made a few modifications to your code.  Caveat Emptor :-)